# AngularJS: How to add a class with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my markup I'm using ng-repeat to add text to each li element plus I want to add a class (in addition to the 'fa' class). So far I'm doing this:

```
<ul class='social-icons' ng-repeat="social in myCtrl.socialArr">
        <li><i class="fa" ng-class={{social.iconClass}}></i><label>{{social.label}}</label></li>
</ul>
```

..but it's not working

in my controller I have:

```
self.socialArr = [
    {
        label: 'Facebook',
        url: 'facebook.com/',
        iconClass: 'fa-facebook'
    },{
        label: 'Twitter',
        url: 'twitter.com/',
        iconClass: 'fa-twitter'
    }...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<ul class='social-icons'>
  <li ng-repeat="social in myCtrl.socialArr">
    <i class="fa" ng-class="social.iconClass"></i>
    <label>{{social.label}}</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have no `conditional` logic, you can basically just use traditional `class` itself, which would improve performance as `ng-class` directive would un-neccessarly trigger the `digest` cycles when in your case its not needed at all.

```
<ul class='social-icons' ng-repeat="social in myCtrl.socialArr">
<li>
   <i class="fa" class={{social.iconClass}}></i>
      <label>{{social.label}}</label>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are passing `{{expression}}` which is evaluted to `string`. But `ng-class` expect `expression` [`ng-class="expression"`].

You can use any of the following:

1. With `ng-class` directive.

   a. `ng-class="expression"`

   b. `class="ng-class: expression;"`
2. With `Interpolation` [`{{expression}}`]

   `class="{{expression}}"`

Note: `::` is for `one time binding`[doc link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

Answer (score 0):

`<i class="fa {{::social.iconClass}}">`
This is the most performant way, since no watchers are created.